# Create graphs by group in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data that has different groupings.

The amount of rows could change from data pull to data pull.

I need to create graphs by these groupings that can change dynamically each time I run the data.

Is their a way to do this without having the change the data for each grouping each time?

Comment: Are you using vba to handle the data pull or to create the graph?

Comment: No im not.  Its an export from SAS.  Im open to suggestions though.  Everytime I make a change its this huge long fix prone to mistakes because its all by hand.

Comment: If you would like to make VBA to do any of this, please give some example data with columns and what the graph/graphs should look like (what the x-axis, y-axis, and series should have for columns). Also what the file type is like that you are importing would help.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Data into a table in excel, then use the table reference for the graph, preferable a pivot chart. Data can be added at the bottom of a set of data set up as a table and the additional rows will be added to the table.

Here are some links about setting up tables and pivot tables/charts up.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Pivot-Tables-in-Excel

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaOtCWxx3xU

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-d09e4d07-8cd6-4b60-afad-8fb67418800f

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for something that would show all the graphs at once instead of having to change the filters.

Comment: For that you could simply make different graphs I would think. And as alluded to in a comment by Branden Keck, you could create a vba code to import your data and make the graphs. Easiest way would be to manually do the entire process once with the "Record Macro" on then modify that code.  Or you could also create a template that has the graphs and just import data into the table assuming that updates the table in excel.